# If file exists, overwrite it?

Tags: c#, file

I'm creating an application to backup files and I need to check if the file exist and if so overwrite it.

This is what I have so far:

```
private void Copy(string sourceDir, string targetDir)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir);

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
    {
        File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file)));
        logWindow.AppendText("\nCopying file" + file + "Complete");
    }

    foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir))
    {    
        Copy(directory, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(directory)));
        logWindow.AppendText("\n" + directory);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to **`File.Copy`** you can simple define it to be overwritten like this:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file)), true)
```

[**`File.Exists`** Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if (File.Exists(file))
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: It worth to mention a possible race condition here

Comment: @zerkms File.Copy itself can overwrite a file as well.

Comment: Changing File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file)), true) worked for me

Comment: +1. Note that `Copy` copies attributes too, so beware of R/O files (and other permission issues).

Comment: @dbc he wants true as he wants to overwrite the file and as stated on the documents `true if the destination file can be overwritten; otherwise, false. `